# How to cut float value to 2 decimal points

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Dataframe with a float column. The values in that column have many decimal points but I only need 2 decimal points. I don't want to round, but truncate the value after the second digit.

this is what I have so far, however with this operation i always get NaN's:

```
t['latitude']=[18.398, 18.4439, 18.346, 37.5079, 38.11, 38.2927]
sub = "."
t['latitude'].astype(str).str.slice(start=t['latitude'].astype(str).str.find(sub), stop=t['latitude'].astype(str).str.find(sub)+2)
```

Output:

```
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
5   NaN
Name: latitude, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest way to truncate:

```py
t = pd.DataFrame()
t['latitude']=[18.398, 18.4439, 18.346, 37.5079, 38.11, 38.2927]
t['latitude'] = (t['latitude'] * 100).astype(int) / 100
print(t)
>>
latitude
0     18.39
1     18.44
2     18.34
3     37.50
4     38.11
5     38.29
```

Comment: Awesome! It´s that simple! thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.round` -

```py
s = pd.Series([18.3988, 18.4439, 18.3467, 37.5079, 38.1102, 38.2927])
s_rounded = np.round(s, 2)
```

**Output**

```
0    18.40
1    18.44
2    18.35
3    37.51
4    38.11
5    38.29
dtype: float64
```

If you don't want to round, but just truncate -

```py
s.astype(str).str.split('.').apply(lambda x: str(x[0]) + '.' + str(x[1])[:2])
```

**Output**

```
0    18.39
1    18.44
2    18.34
3    37.50
4    38.11
5    38.29
dtype: object
```

Comment: *I don't want to round*

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.trunc`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.trunc.html) for a vectorial operation:

```
n = 2 # number of decimals to keep
np.trunc(df['latitude'].mul(10**n)).div(10**n)

# to assign
# df['latitude'] = np.trunc(df['latitude'].mul(10**n)).div(10**n)
```

output:

```
0    18.39
1    18.44
2    18.34
3    37.50
4    38.11
5    38.29
Name: latitude, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import math

for i in t['latitude']:
    math.trunc(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is `Serious.round`, but you can also try `.str.extract`

```py
t['latitude'] = (t['latitude'].astype(str)
                 .str.extract('(.*\.\d{0,2})')
                 .astype(float))
```

```
print(t)

   latitude
0     18.39
1     18.44
2     18.34
3     37.50
4     38.11
5     38.29
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 12.3614
y = round(x,2)
print(y) // 12.36
```

Comment: Kindly add a line or two to explain what you are doing. This will help the readers to understand the answer more clearly. - [from review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32043629)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

t = [18.398, 18.4439, 18.346, 37.5079, 38.11, 38.2927]
truncated_lat=[]

for lat in t:
    truncated_lat.append(float(re.findall('[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}', str(lat))[0]))
print(truncated_lat)
```

Output:

```
[18.39, 18.44, 18.34, 37.5, 38.11, 38.29]
```